# InvalidArgumentException: URI must be a string or UriInterface in Guzzle

Tags: guzzle

I get a guzzle error as above , when i am sending the following code from a drupal 8 site:

```
 $url="https://mywebsite.com/index.php";
 $client = \Drupal::httpClient();
 $client->setDefaultOption( array('verify' ,false));
 $post_data = $form_state->cleanValues()->getValues();

 $request = $client->post($url, $post_data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line was causing it to think this was the URL. When I took it out it works okay

```
$client->setDefaultOption(array('verify', false));
```

Answer (score -2):

Basically, it should work (because the `$url` obviously is a string).

If it doesn't, check the stack trace of the exception (is it this call, or maybe another?).

And provide the Guzzle version please.

Comment: Giving basic troubleshooting steps usually isn't helpful, try the example given first yourself and then give what you see at the very least, but only as a comment unless you have an actual answer. This isn't an answer, its a suggestion for finding the answer.