# Symfony 4 - URI must be a string or UriInterface - Guzzle

Tags: php, request, guzzle, akeneo

When I try to make a request by PHP Guzzle 7 I am getting the ([2021-10-05 15:50:44] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception InvalidArgumentException: "A 'contents' key is required" at /home/allen/Documents/pim/pim-community-standard/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/MultipartStream.php line 86 {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): A 'contents' key is required at /home/allen/Documents/pim/pim-community-standard/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/MultipartStream.php:86)"} [])

I am trying you upload a picture in Akeneo Pim 5, the endpoint documentation is:
[Akeneo Pim 5 - API Documentation](https://api.akeneo.com/api-reference.html#post_media_files)

Someone know what I am doing wrong?

[Image 01 - Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqtf4.png)

[Image 02 - Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rpwW.png)

This request on postman works fine, but I am trying to do it with a guzzle, I already have the first request getting the token.
My Request:

```
        $client2 = new Client();
        $file = '/tmp/T_square.jpg';
        $url2 = "http://akeneo-pim.local/api/rest/v1/media-files";
        $response2 = $client2->request('POST', $url2, [
            'headers'  => [
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $response->access_token,
                'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data',
                'Accept' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            ],
            'multipart' => [
                'product' => [
                    "identifier" => "teste_image", 
                    "attribute" => "picture", 
                    "locale" => null, 
                    "scope" => null
                ],
                'file' => fopen($file, 'r'),
            ]
        ]);
```

Comment: Guzzle is not particularly helpful with the error message alone (your URI **is** a string, compare: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43666094/367456). Double check the URI is correct and can resolve to an absolute URI (provide one, in your example it is relative, or  [set the **Client**s' `base_uri`](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#creating-a-client) (compare: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44494277/367456). Still then this error can show up. If so, use a step debugger then and verify with an exception break point to see which concrete value triggered throwing the exception.

Comment: It did not work!

Comment: Sorry for the repetition: _"Still then this error can show up. If so, use a step debugger then and verify with an exception break point to see which concrete value triggered throwing the exception."_ The (a) step debugger for PHP is _Xdebug_ - https://xdebug.org/

Comment: I am not getting the xdebug working, I've updated the question with more details, and postman screenshots. On postman it works fine.